# Infinite loop in python from user input

Tags: python, loops

I am writing Python code counting up to the number the user provides, but I get into an infinite loop when running the code. Please note I tried commenting out lines 3 and 4 and replaced "userChoice" with a number, let's say for example 5, and it works fine.

```
import time

print "So what number do you want me to count up to?"
userChoice = raw_input("> ")

i = 0
numbers = []

while i < userChoice:
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is %d" % i
    time.sleep(1)

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: So is there a code that I am missing?

Comment: What is the input that causes the error and can you provide a sample of the output when the error is occurring?

Comment: If I pick any number, the code will print the number +1 indefinitely

Comment: So what number do you want me to count up to?
> 5
At the top i is 0
Numbers now:  [0]
At the bottom i is 1
At the top i is 1
Numbers now:  [0, 1]
At the bottom i is 2
At the top i is 2
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2]
At the bottom i is 3
At the top i is 3
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3]
At the bottom i is 4
At the top i is 4
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
At the bottom i is 5
At the top i is 5
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
At the bottom i is 6
At the top i is 6
Numbers now:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
At the bottom i is 7
At the top i is 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` returns a string, not `int`. You can fix the issue by converting user response to `int`:

```
userChoice = int(raw_input("> "))
```

In Python 2.x objects of different types are [compared by the type name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) so that explains the original behavior since `'int' < 'string'`:

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a number with a string in:

```
while i < userChoice:
```

The string will always be greater than the number. At least in Python 2 where these are comparable.

You need to turn `userChoice` into a number:

```
userChoice = int(raw_input("> "))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dan! I'll have to pay attention to python variable types next time.